# Delete numpy 2D memmap array if sum equals 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-memmap

I am using a numpy `memmap` object that acts as a 2D array:

```
In [8]: data_2d.shape  
Out[8]: (16777216, 50)
```

What is the best way to delete a row in which the sum of that row is zero?

Comment: For an ordinary array you can delete rows by `data1 = data[mask,:]` where `mask` is a boolean (or `where` list) of the rows you want to keep.  `np.delete` can do the same thing, given the rows you want to delete.  But either case produces a new array.  I'm not sure that will work with a `memmap`.